# Почему блок смещается за пределы страницы, при position fixed блока header,

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrapper {
  min-width: 320px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 55px 131px;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-container li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
}

.header-list {
  display: flex;
}

.header-list li a {
  color: rgba(38, 50, 56, 1);
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.header-list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.button-talk button {
  border-color: rgba(38, 50, 56, 1);
  border-width: 2px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Шапка сайта -->
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#"><img class="logo-img" src="images/Britlex.png" alt="Логотип"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="main-menu">
        <ul class="header-list">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="button-talk">
        <button>Let's Talk</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доюавьте `left: 0` к блоку с стилям `position: fixed`

```css
.wrapper {
  min-width: 320px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 55px 131px;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-container li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
}

.header-list {
  display: flex;
}

.header-list li a {
  color: rgba(38, 50, 56, 1);
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.header-list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.button-talk button {
  border-color: rgba(38, 50, 56, 1);
  border-width: 2px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Шапка сайта -->
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#"><img class="logo-img" src="images/Britlex.png" alt="Логотип"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="main-menu">
        <ul class="header-list">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="button-talk">
        <button>Let's Talk</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Если честно уже манипулировал с left, но до 0 не допер)